# Passive form of sentences

Tags: passive-voice, gerunds

What is the passive form of such these sentences:

- **I enjoy watching TV.**
- **I don't like playing football.**

or

- **I don't want to play football.**
- **I'd like to drink a cup of tea.**

In normal sentences usually, we simply move the object to the subject of the passive sentence and then we use the passive form of the verb (*eg: People love him => He is loved by people*) but in this case, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passive forms would be as follows:

> TV watching is enjoyed by me.
>   Football playing is not liked by me.

But they sound so unusual that, outside of a mental exercise, nobody would ever actually use them.

---

There is no direct passive for the additional sentences. (Although a similar kind of translation might be made, it wouldn't be exact.)

Comment: Question is edited.

Comment: To play football is wanted by me.

Comment: I was thinking "Watching TV is something I enjoy" "Playing football is not something I like"

Comment: These are the passive of "enjoy" but not the passive of the gerund, which is not what  X478 asked.  Unless I misunderstand the question, that is.

Comment: @RonJensen *To play football* is not an object . . . (The use of the infinitive only makes sense in the active voice.)

Comment: Thank you both. I needed both of them! I was expecting a "being" right there as @Andrew said. This is almost a new topic for me which I'm studying.

Comment: I'm editing my questions frequently. If it's possible you guys edit your answers too. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

*(Edit)  Ok, so you don't want to make the gerund/infinitive passive, you just want to make the sentence passive.  Got it.*

The passive voice sounds awkward in this context, and would not normally be something a native speaker would say.  Still, if you are determined to do so, the rule is generally the same.  Invert subject and object, and change the verb to the passive

> Watching TV **is enjoyed** by me.
>
> Playing football **is not liked** by me.
>
> To play football **is not wanted** by me.
>
> To drink a cup of tea **is not wanted/desired** by me.

Again, all of these are very unusual.  In general, we do not use the passive voice for verbs of emotion or perception such as *want, like, desire, think, enjoy*, etc. -- but there are exceptions.  For example, in a formal context, this kind of sentence sounds fine:

> The sumptuous meal **was enjoyed** by all the guests.

---

Original answer, for general interest

"Being watched" is the passive of "watching", and "being played" is the passive of "playing", but neither really works in this context.  With verbs like "enjoy" or "like", you would need an activity where you are the object of the gerund.  For example:

> I enjoy someone else cooking for me ⟶  I enjoy **being cooked for** (by someone)
>
> I enjoy someone else singing to me ⟶ I enjoy **being sung to** (by someone)